# What does kube-proxy `--masquerade-all=true` mean?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

The [kube-proxy admin page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-proxy/) says:

```
--masquerade-all       If using the pure iptables proxy, SNAT everything
```

But it does explain in detail.

- When should I set `--masquerade-all` to true?
- And what problem it solves?
- What could happen if it set `--masquerade-all=false`? What is the difference compared to `--masqurade-all=true`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you enable this and route the service IP range to your nodes then it will be possible to reach the service IPs from outside of the cluster.

The discussion is in [Issue #24224](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24224) and it's implemented in [PR 24429](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/24429).